# How to handle One-to-Many Join without repeat rows

Tags: sql-server

In MS SQL Server I have two tables [Products] and [Product_img] with relationship (ONE TO MANY).

SELECT p_id, name FROM dbo.products

| 15 |  | name1 |

| 17 |  | name2 |

SELECT p_id, path FROM dbo.product_img

| 1.jpg |   | 15 |

| 2.jpg |   | 15 |

| 3.jpg|    | 17 |

| 4.jpg |   | 17 |

SELECT dbo.product_img.p_id, dbo.products.name, dbo.product_img.path FROM dbo.product_img INNER JOIN dbo.products ON dbo.product_img.p_id = dbo.products.p_id

| 15 |  | name1 |   | 1.jpg |

| 15 |  | name1 |   | 2.jpg |

| 17 |  | name2 |   | 3.jpg |

| 17 |  | name2 |   | 4.jpg |

What is the SQL statement that can show the tables like this (with out repeating)?

| 15 |  | name1 |   | 1.jpg |   | 2.jpg |

| 17 |  | name2 |   | 3.jpg |   | 4.jpg |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USE MAX AND MIN

```
SELECT
  dbo.product_img.p_id
, dbo.products.name
, MAX(dbo.product_img.path)
, MIN(dbo.product_img.path) 
FROM dbo.product_img 
INNER JOIN dbo.products 
    ON dbo.product_img.p_id = dbo.products.p_id
 GROUP BY dbo.product_img.p_id , dbo.products.name
```

Comment: No problems at all, just be weary though that if you have more than one 2 images you are going to have problems, so i would strongly avoid structuring your table like the way you have wanted to

Answer (score 4):

If you can have more than two images per product you can do this to get one column with the img path's.

```
select
  p.p_id,
  p.name,
  stuff((select ', '+i.path
         from product_img as i 
         where p.p_id = i.p_id
         for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') as path  
from products as p
```

Result

```
p_id    name    path
-----   -----   ------------
15      name1   1.jpg, 2.jpg
17      name2   3.jpg, 4.jpg
```